# getAttribute method with jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `filter` to return a particular element. I want to know why `.getAttribute` is not working with returned object while it is working fine with `.attr()`. [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/37pAZ/4/)

```
var c = $('ul li').filter(function(){
 if($(this).text()=='d')
    return this;
});

console.log(c.getAttribute('value'));
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FSAYR/

Comment: console.log(c.attr('value')) Use this

Comment: @PraJen: Yes it is working fine with .attr() but my question is how to get it work with getAttribute

Comment: @amit many has posted the answer i think so

Comment: It should be noted that `<li>` doesn't have a value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getAttribute()` is a method associated with DOM object not with with jQuery object.

If you want to use it you need to get DOM object like

```
console.log(c[0].getAttribute('value'))
```

or

```
console.log(c.get(0).getAttribute('value'))
```

Comment: No, I post the crux then go on to edit if you found half-baked/incorrect answer then why don't you just downvote that.

Comment: I'm just teasing you!  You always post correct and useful information.

Comment: Thanks, for posting answer. This is really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing javascript with jquery. `getAttribute` is a javascript function.

try this

```
console.log(c.attr('value'))
```

Or simple

```
console.log(c.val())
```

Comment: To get the value, would be better the c.val() function?

Answer (score 1):

`var c` is array object and not single object. Use index like below :

```
console.log(c[0].getAttribute('value'))
              ^--- 0 index
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37pAZ/8/)**